# How to pull a component through a panel cutout using a screw mechanism?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, mechanical, fasteners

I have a camera fixed to a cube frame structure made from aluminium extrusion. The frame will be covered by a 3 mm thick fibreglass enclosure (this is highly rigid) with a cutout for the camera, which sticks out of the enclosure by around 2.5 mm.

The enclosure is open at the bottom so is simply placed over the cube structure and bolted onto it. The challenge is that the camera needs to be moved back for the enclosure to fit over it and then forward again when in place.

I was thinking this might be achieved using some kind of screw mechanism whereby the screws could pull the camera forward through the enclosure cutout when it is in place.

Does anyone have any ideas how this might be implemented?

Here are some basic renderings for context:

[image: Isometric View]

[image: Side View]

Comment: Use of sketches or drawings may make an answer easier to find.

Comment: A spring? Push the camera inside the cube's volume when you slide the cover over it, then let it bounce out of the hole you presumably made. Or frame challenge: Attach the fiberglass front when the camera is already in place.

Comment: Spring seems useful... do you know of some hardware I could buy to implement this? I'm thinking some kind of screw and spring combination to adjust the cameras position from outside the enclosure.